# Proof verification of non vanishing of $ ~L(1, \chi) \neq 0~$ for real valued character

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, solution-verification, l-functions

I am self studying analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol introduction to analytic number theory and I am asking for solution verification for a part of Theorem 6.20 of Apostol.

I am adding it's image -
 [image]

> I have only doubt in proving that $L(1, \chi) \neq 0$ .

**My attempt** - Assuming Part (b) , if I put $x\to\infty$ in part (b) , then if $ L(1, \chi ) =0 $ for some $n$, then $B(x) \to \infty = O(1)$ , which is a contradiction.

Is my proof right? Can someone please verify.

Edit 1 -> This is the proof given in Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory. Please note that he doesn't proves  how L(1 , $\chi ) \neq $ 0 . 
That's why I am asking for verification of my argument. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Its better for you to type the mathematics in the images

Comment: @Calvin khor actually 1 user reuns is misunderstanding the problem. So, I added image .

Comment: Tim:  You've been around awhile, so I think you should replace the images with $\LaTeX$ markup, at least in quoting the original exercise, and perhaps leaving Apostol's proof of (a),(b) as merely a link to the image.  The very length of those images distracts from your intended approach, to assume (a),(b) and ask only about the non-vanishing of $L(1, \chi)$.  Use the space allowed in the body of the Question instead to focus on your interest in that aspect of the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming (b), if L(1,X)=0 then B(x) = O(1), and this is in contradiction with (a).  So given these results (a) and (b) it follows that L(1,X) is not zero.

[Edit: Originally I mistyped this as "B(x) = O(x)"]

Comment: Did you mean to say "then $B(x) = O(x)$?  That would not contradict (a), since $B(x) \in O(x)$ could very well tend to infinity as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @hardmath If User Answering question meant that B(x) =O(1) , then was answer correct?

Comment: @hardmath  So, You means that my argument is wrong .Why so ? Can you please tell in detail as I wasn't able to understand reuns answer and he didn't elaborated. So, I thought I am right as no - one was answering. Luckily for me there is a guy whohas now posyted an answer. So, If you answer / explain in detail then it will really help me , man. It's my humble requets if you can spare some time for this.

Comment: @Tim: I said your argument is correct, that $B(x)$ is bounded (or $O(1)$, same thing) is inconsistent with the property (a) that your Question **takes as given**.  So hopefully we are on the same page.  My Comment on this answer was similar to yours, that perhaps not $O(x)$ but $O(1)$ should be written there, so we get "contradiction with (a).".

Comment: @hardmath Thanks a lot !

Comment: @StuartPresnell  Did you meant B(x)=O(1) in line 1 of your answer?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant B(x) = O(1)

Answer (score 1):

Why is $B(x)=O(1)$ a contradiction. What can you say about $A(n)$ (hint : look at $A(p^k)$ or at the Euler product of $\sum_n A(n)n^{-s}$, you'll find that $A(n)\ge 0$ and for $p> q$, $A(p^2)\ge 1$, since $\sum_p \frac1p \approx \lim_{s\to 1} \log \zeta(s)=\infty$ we get $\sum_n \frac{A(n)}{n^{1/2}}\ge \sum_{p> q} \frac{A(p^2)}{p}=\infty$ )

Also it is worth noticing that for complex Dirichlet characters $\bmod q$, if $L(1,\chi)=0$ then so does $L(1,\overline{\chi})=0$ thus $\prod_{\chi\bmod q} L(s,\chi)$ has at least a simple zero at $s=1$ which is a contradiction because its $\log $ is $\sum_{p^k} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k} \sum_{\chi\bmod q} \chi(p^k)=\varphi(q)\sum_{p^k\equiv 1\bmod q} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k} $ which is non-negative at $s=1+\epsilon$.

Comment: 1. if x->$\infty$ , then B(x) -> $\infty $ but if B(x) =O(1) then B(x) becomes bounded, by Definition of Big O as B(x) -> $\infty$  . Can you please tell if my argument is right?  2.  For Complex valued characters Apostol has already given a nice explanation in chapter-7 which is clear to me.

Comment: Why do you think $B(x)\to \infty$...

Comment: if I put x->$\infty$ then B(x) ->$\infty$

Comment: ???? How do you know that $\lim_{x\to \infty} B(x)=\infty$

Comment: it's given in the statement of theorem  in the image in the question( part (a) to be precise ) . I am using that. Is my argument right?

Comment: You don't have any argument. Once you know that $B(x)$ is unbounded then $L(1,\chi)=0\implies B(x)=O(1)$ is a contradiction, if you are not confortable with that then you have a problem..

Comment: I was just asking if it was right to think about non vanishing in this way or not!!

Comment: Ok, then no you are not thinking right.

Comment: can you please tell what mistake is in using unboundedness of B(x) and then using (a) ?

Comment: my question is what mistake I am making , whatever you have written in 1st paragraph proves  that B(x) ->$\infty$ as x->$\infty$ .

Comment: I've upvoted because reuns tackles the hard part of the Apostol exercise, and I think this content has lasting value.  The inference that $L(1, \chi) \neq 0$ from (a),(b) is comparatively easy.