# Quick Query: Big Oh manipulation in Apostol analytic number theory proof

Tags: analytic-number-theory

There has been discussion of Apostol's proof 6.20 on the nonvanishing of $L(1,\,\,\chi )$ for real nonprincipal $\chi$ elsewhere, but my question focuses on a particular manipulation of big-oh notation I am unsure about.

In the proof, Apostol replaces the term $$\sum\limits_{n\,\, \le \,\sqrt x } {\frac{{\chi (n)}}{{\sqrt n }}} \left( {...\,\, + \,\,O\left( {\sqrt {\frac{n}{x}} } \right)} \right)$$ by $$...\,\,\, + \,\,\,O\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}\,\sum\limits_{n\,\, \le \,\,\sqrt x } {\left| {\chi (n)} \right|} } \right)$$

Why has the modulus sign been included?

Also, is it safe to assume that because $$\sum\limits_{n\,\, \le \,\,x} {\chi (n)} \,\, = \,\,O(1)$$ then $$O\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}\,\sum\limits_{n\,\, \le \,\,\sqrt x } {\left| {\chi (n)} \right|} } \right)\,\, = \,\,O\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}} \right)$$

The full proof can be accessed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3503145/proof-verification-of-non-vanishing-of-l1-chi-neq-0-for-real-valued-ch), but I assume my specific question on how big-oh notation is being handled with the Dirichlet character is independent of the context!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to apply the triangle inequality to bound $\sum\limits_{n\le x}\frac{\chi(n)}{\sqrt n}$.

$$\left|\sum\limits_{n\le x}\frac{\chi(n)}{\sqrt n}\right| \le \sum_{n\le x}\frac{|\chi(n)|}{\sqrt n}$$

Comment: Sorry, I can't see it with this explanation. As far as I can see, once the product of $\sum\limits_{n\,\, \le \,\sqrt x } {\frac{{\chi (n)}}{{\sqrt n }}} $  and  ${O\left( {\sqrt {\frac{n}{x}} } \right)}$  results in $O\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}\,\sum\limits_{n\,\, \le \,\,\sqrt x } {\chi (n)} } \right)$.  Surely we just now apply $\sum\limits_{n\,\, \le \,\,x} {\chi (n)} \,\, = \,\,O(1)$  ?  I don't see why the modulus is relevant. Thanks.

Comment: @Ken_M_W: no, the product of $\frac{\chi(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $O(\sqrt{n/x})$ is $O\left(\frac{|\chi(n)|}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$, so when you sum over $n \leq \sqrt{x}$, you get $O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \sum_{n \leq \sqrt{x}} |\chi(n)|\right)$.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thank you so much for this information and clarification. I am not sure of the justification for this manipulation regarding inclusion of the modulus sign when combining big-oh with the expression containing the Dirichlet character; Apostol does not justify it here (or anywhere else in his book, as far as I can find). Any pointers to help me understand this would be much appreciated; I am knew to big-oh processing. Thank you!